# Express JS passing middleware through controller function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wanted to know if it is possible to pass middleware in the controller function
routes.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
router.get('/home', home.get);
```

home.js

```
module.exports.get = (req, res) => {
  res.send("Welcome to HOME");
};
```

I want to pass middleware in the get function of home.js, one method I know is to call the middleware function and then pass the controller function as next callback

```
module.exports.get = (req, res) => {
   authCheckMiddleware(req, res, () => {
       res.send("Welcome to HOME");
   })
};
```

If there any approach? to pass the middleware in the function defination or something for home.js

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding your middleware function as an argument preceding the actual controller:

```
router.get('/home', authCheckMiddleware, home.get);
```